# arfima model "'x' is a list, but does not have components 'x' and 'y'"

Tags: r, plot

R Software

```
set.seed(1000)
sim <- arfima.sim(1000, model = list(phi = c(0.2, 0.1), dfrac = 0.4, theta = 0.9))
fit <- arfima(sim, order = c(2, 0, 1), back=T)
plot(fit)
```

> Error in xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) :
>
> 'x' is a list, but does not have components 'x' and 'y'

How can I plot `fit`? I think the problem is that the value of `fit` is supposed to be the `y` values while the `x` are the numbers `1,2,3,4` denoting the observation number. Anyone have a solution for this?

I want to plot the values i get from the arfima model. It is like i am trying to plot the actual and the fitted values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is: *What* do you want to plot? If it is the time series data including model predictions, try:

```
set.seed(1000)
sim <- arfima.sim(1000, model = list(phi = c(0.2, 0.1), dfrac = 0.4, theta = 0.9))
fit <- arfima(sim, order = c(2, 0, 1), back=T)
plot(predict(fit, n.ahead = 5))
```

`predict(fit, n.ahead)` uses your ARFIMA model to predict `n.ahead` steps into the future.

To plot fitted values for every mode you can use `fitted(fit)`, e.g.

```
library(tidyverse);
cbind.data.frame(Data = sim, fitted(fit)) %>%
    rowid_to_column("idx") %>%
    gather(what, value, -idx) %>%
    ggplot(aes(idx, value, colour = what)) +
    facet_wrap(~ what, ncol = 1, scales = "free_y") +
    geom_line()
```

[image]

Comment: no, i want to plot the fitted values from the arfima model i got, so i could compare it to the original values

Comment: @korzuen You can extract the fitted values from the ARFIMA fit object for every mode with `fitted(fit)`. These are all well-documented functions from the [`arfima` documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/arfima/arfima.pdf).

Comment: You're welcome @korzuen. Please consider closing the question by setting the check mark next to the answer.